# Web Scraping in Python, confused with path

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing

I have basic knowledge of scraping.
Here is a basic example:

```
page = requests.get('some_website.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
desc = tree.path('//div[@class = "my class"]/text()')
```

And my desc would return whatever is in that `div`.
But how do I proceed if my javascript is more complex

```
<tr>
    <th class="my class">some text</th>
    <td>some text</td>
</tr>
```

I need only the part that is inside `<td></td>` that is inside `<tr></tr>`
And how would I proceed if the `<tr>` would be inside a `<div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably go through an XPath tutorial to have a better understanding.

> I need only the part that is inside `<td></td>` that is inside `<tr></tr>`
>   And how would I proceed if the `<tr>` would be inside a `<div>`

In your case it would be:

```
//div[@class = "my class"]//tr/td/text()
```

If you know "some text" beforehand, you can go sideways with [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//div[@class = "my class"]//th[. = "some text"]/following-sibling::td/text()
```

Comment: and if `<tr> `has a class I would just do `//div[@class = "div class"]//tr[@class = "tr class"]/td/text()`, right?

Comment: @AK9309 yup, looks good. Note that though it would not handle the situation if `tr` has multiple classes - in this case, you might get away with `contains()`.